# import worksheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

i have some problems with my actual Import Sub. It always abort the Code at import "After".

```
Sub DatImport1()
Dim QWB As Workbook, ZWB As Workbook
Dim QWS As Worksheet, ZWS As Worksheet
Set ZWB = ThisWorkbook
Set ZWS = ZWB.ActiveSheet
Set QWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test.xlsx")
Set QWS = QWB.Worksheets("Table1")
QWS.Cells.Copy After:=ZWS(Sheets.Count)
QWB.Close
End Sub
```

What i have to change to bring this import to work correctly?
thanks for your support!

Comment: Do you want to import a complete sheet (so that your destination workbook gets an additional sheet) or do you want to copy the data of `QWS` into an existing sheet?

Comment: QWS is a Worksheet Object, as is ZWS so if you just want to copy the worksheet, no need to use the `.Cells` of QWS and `Sheets.Count` would be something used on a Workbook object, not a Worksheet Object. Try `QWS.Copy After:= ZWS` instead.

Comment: ... or `QWS.Copy After:=ZWB.Sheets(ZWB.Sheets.Count)` when `ZWS` would be irrelevant (redundant). BTW, `QWS.Cells` is another way to say `QWS.Range("A1:XFD1048576")`.

Comment: with QWS.Copy After:= ZWS the Macro is running perfectly as modul in the Workbook, but when i put the same code in my personal.xlsb then the code gets a runtimeerror because "Copy for the object Worksheet is going wrong".

Comment: If you put the code into your personal workbook, `ZWB` will be set to the Personal Workbook (`ThisWorkbook`), and you cannot copy a sheet into that. Don't know your exact requirements, but I assume you want to copy the sheet into the active workbook - so replace  `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Import Sheet From Closed Workbook After the Active Sheet

**The Calling Procedure (Usage)**

```vb
Sub ImportTable1() ' shows in the macro dialog
    
    Const FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Test.xlsx"
    Const SHEET_ID As Variant = "Table1"
    Dim PROC_TITLE As String: PROC_TITLE = "Import Sheet " _
        & IIf(VarType(SHEET_ID) = vbString, """" & SHEET_ID & """", SHEET_ID)
        
    Dim IsSuccess As Boolean:
    IsSuccess = ImportSheetAfterActiveSheet(FILE_PATH, SHEET_ID)

    If IsSuccess Then MsgBox "Sheet imported.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

    ' Instead of all of the above, one can simply use the following one-liner:
    'ImportSheetAfterActiveSheet "C:\Test.xlsx", "Table1"

End Sub
```

**A Useful Method (Written As a Function)**

```vb
Function ImportSheetAfterActiveSheet( _
    ByVal FilePath As String, _
    ByVal SheetID As Variant) _
As Boolean ' doesn't show in the macro dialog
    Const PROC_TITLE As String _
        = "Import Sheet From Closed Workbook After the Active Sheet"
        Dim Msg As String
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start an error-handling routine
    
        Msg = "Could not create a reference to the active sheet!"
    ' Reference the active sheet.
    Dim dsh As Object: Set dsh = ActiveSheet
        If dsh Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox Msg, vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Function
        End If
    
        Msg = "Could not find the file """ & FilePath & """!"
    ' Open and reference the source workbook.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    
        Msg = "The sheet " & IIf(VarType(SheetID) = vbString, _
            """" & SheetID & """", SheetID) & " was not found in workbook """ _
            & swb.Name & """ containing " & swb.Sheets.Count & " sheet(s)!"
    ' Reference the source sheet.
    Dim ssh As Object: Set ssh = swb.Sheets(SheetID)
    
        Msg = "Something went wrong when copying """ & ssh.Name & """ to """ _
            & dsh.Name & """!"
    ssh.Copy After:=dsh
    
    ImportSheetAfterActiveSheet = True
    
ProcExit:
    ' Close the workbook.
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop
        If TypeName(swb) = "Workbook" Then
            swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine.
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description & vbLf & vbLf & vbLf & Msg, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```